# Check if div is empty before clicking next page button

Tags: jquery, html, css

I Have two buttons in my page. One is " Update Address" and "Next Page". Update Address redirected to Address Book and user need to select an address from it. But if user click "Next page", before updating the "Address", an error message should be shown.

```
<form>
    <div class="update-address"> <button>Update Address</button></div>
    <div class="to-address">
        <div>
            <div class="next-page"> <button>Next Page</button></div>
            <div class="error-msg"></div>
</form>
```

JS

```
$('.next-page').click(function () {
    if (!$.trim($('.to-address').html()).length) {
        $('.error-msg').html("Kindly update shipping address");
    }
```

help me on fixing this.

Comment: Please use the `edit` button to add code to the question. Please also format it properly, because this is completely unreadable right now

Comment: <div class="to-address"> is never closed **</div>**

Comment: I believe the code in the question is properly aligned.. i ll delete the comment now if it unreadable. @rory McCrossan

Comment: you can use `event.preventDefault()` in click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this: *just adding one hidden field if it is applicable*

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $('.next-page').click(function () {
    if($('.update-status').val() != 1){
        $('.error-msg').html("Kindly update shipping address");
        return false;
    }
  });
  
  $('.update-address button').click(function(){
    $('.update-status').val(1);
    return false
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form>
    <div class="update-address"> <button>Update Address</button></div>
    <div class="to-address">
        <div>
            <div class="next-page"> <button>Next Page</button></div>
            <div class="error-msg"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <input type="hidden" value="0" class="update-status">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix html for closing div tag.
Use [is](http://api.jquery.com/is/) to check empty div. To display error message use `text` not `html`.

```js
$('.next-page').click(function () {
    if (!$('.to-address').is(':empty')) {
        $('.error-msg').text("Kindly update shipping address");
    }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="update-address">
  <button>Update Address</button>
</div>
<div class="to-address">
</div>
<div class="next-page">
  <button>Next Page</button>
</div>
<div class="error-msg"></div>
```